# Can `kubectl wait` work for secrets generated by deployment? If not, any alternative in bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, kubernetes

I try to use bash script to run a few k8s commands. During the deployment, I need to wait for a secret to be generated by cert-manager or Vault before it can continue. I know there is a command called `kubectl wait` but it doesn't seem to work with `secret` resources, so I came up with this bash script:

```
  while [ -z "$matched" ]
  do
    echo "Waiting for ($secret_name) to be created"
    matched=$(kubectl get secret $secret_name -n $namespace -o jsonpath="{$path}" --ignore-not-found=true)
    sleep 10;
  done
```

But it fails on first run after waiting for a minute. It only works on second try. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hello @RedGiant. Could you please tell how long have you waited between the first and second run? Also, are there any logs to see what went wrong with your script? More of your code could also be helpful.